# how to check if a rtmp stream alive with php? gen ques

Tags: php, rtmp, fsockopen

Is there a way to check RTMP stream is alive or not with php?
Found something like fsockopen().
But not sure how to use this command to verify stream data.

Answer (score 0):

Found this using rtmpdump:
http://blog.svnlabs.com/how-to-check-rtmp-source-stream-is-live-or-not/